# Windows 10 - System tries to login before wifi connection established

Tags: windows-10

That is. I have enabled `AutoAdminLogon` feature, but after boot, the system says: "we cannot connect right now. Please try again later" (or something like that, I have Russian localization). And I can see that only after that message shown, wifi icon at the bottom right corner changes to 'connected' state. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason for this?

Because depending on WiFi as your primary connection during boot sucks, and is generally a bad idea (especially on a domain) since the WiFi driver/connection often doesn't kick in right away after boot (or worse, not until the user has actually logged in).

*Possible solution:*

Check with your WiFi manufacturer for a utility that will ensure the WiFi connection is up before the login is allowed.  I know Intel WiFi adapters generally have this option once you install the full Wireless ProSet drivers and utilities.

Intel refers to that feature as "Pre-Logon Connect" (PLC), which is a sub-future of what they refer to as Single Sign On (SSO).  [More Info](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-032783.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tp-link archer t4u and there are no vendor drivers yet. But microsoft's driver works well except the described issue.

I found out that if I unplug the wifi dongle before power on, I cannot auto login with the same error message, but if I enter password, I can. Maybe the issue is not related to internet?